# Is it possible to create a pandas dataframe based on dataframe rows from different dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two separate dataframes, `df1` and `df2`. I want to be able to create a new dataframe based on a row from `df1` and row from `df2`.

I need to be able to create a new df, based on row index [1] of df1 & row index [2] of df2

Below is df1

```
df1

   A      B      C
0  1.57   4.40   6.00
1  1.73   3.95   5.00
2  1.26   6.60   12.00
```

df2

```
df2

   D      E       F
0  1.57   4.48    6.25
1  1.27   6.73    11.88
2  1.74   3.99    5.11
```

Expected New_Df

```
   A      B      C     D      E       F
0  1.73   3.95   5.00  1.74   3.99    5.11
```

Comment: The row are many, each df has dynamic rows numbers, df1 has 28, df2 has 35.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `pd.concat`

```py
out = pd.concat([df1.iloc[1], df2.iloc[2]], axis=0).to_frame().T
```

```
print(out)

      A     B    C     D     E     F
0  1.73  3.95  5.0  1.74  3.99  5.11
```

Comment: Does this solution apply, if i need to pick the rows randomly from each dataframe?

Comment: @Bernietechy Yes, just replace the `1` and `2` with your randomly picked row index.

Comment: some rows, give me this `key error: 0`, not quite sure why but other rows are able to concat.

Comment: @Bernietechy Do the two dataframe index starts from 0?

Comment: yes, the dataframes starts at index 0

Comment: @Bernietechy Could you post the code you try?

Comment: have added the  full code below your answer, kindly check. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243947/discussion-between-ynjxsjmh-and-bernietechy).

Comment: @Bernietechy It's not suitable to add extra info as answer.